# Unable to send myself a test Chatter Message

Tags: chatter, connect-api

I am trying to send myself a test Chatter message as the first step towards a proof of concept. The desired outcome is that I will get a private chat message pop up in the bottom right-hand corner of my Salesforce window where it says "Chat".

When I run the following code in execute anonymous:

```
ConnectAPI.ChatterMessages.sendMessage('Test chatter message', 'MY_USER_ID');
```

I get the following error message:

```
ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Too few or too many recipients
```

The documentation (http://bit.ly/1jFlDS7) says that the second parameter should be "Up to nine comma-separated IDs of the users receiving the message."

Things I have already tried:

- '"MY_USER_ID"'
- 'MY_USERID,ANOTHER_USER_ID
- '"MY_USERID","ANOTHER_USER_ID"'

I have looked for Chatter recipes, example documentation, and even searched for the error message on both here and Google but have found nothing.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Got to love that error... it's not like they could have counted the recipients or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to interact with the "Chat" window via the API. The method that you're referencing is for the Private Messages feature (https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=collab_message_send.htm&siteLang=en_US), not for the Chat feature.

(If you still want to get the call to ConnectAPI.ChatterMessages.sendMessage() working, try using only the other user's ID as the second parameter. I don't think you can send private messages to yourself.)