# Sending Chatter Private Message using Apex Trigger/Class

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api

Need to send a Chatter Private Message to the current user whenever they post something inappropriate on the chatterfeed.

I've already got the code to send the message through Apex, but it is throwing me an error:

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Too few or too many recipients

```
if(itemFlagged) {
     ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.sendMessage('Your post has been flagged as inappropriate',UserInfo.getUserId());
     system.debug('##SENDING MESSAGE');
}
```

I saw this post [Unable to send myself a test Chatter Message](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36670/unable-to-send-myself-a-test-chatter-message) where it states that the error was due to the private message is being sent to the user itself, in which I assumes that it was sending the private message through the current user's context.

How do I send a chatter message to the current user using ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.sendMessage() function? Is there a workaround this?

Comment: I suggest you try using the search box at the upper right of the screen to see if you can locate code that's previously been posted here for one reason or another (help getting a trigger to work, etc). You can also try using [Find SFInfo](http://findsf.info/) as a search engine that will return only SF related results from Documentation, boards (including here), blogs, etc. Requests for people to write code for you normally get closed.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for that. You must have misunderstood my question, I was just asking for any sample codes with regards to sending chatter messages. If not, any approach that would let me send chatter message through apex would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.sendMessage() method? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterMessages_sendMessage_2

Comment: @alouie 
I've tried using it within apex. I don't know if I'm using the right syntax, but it is showing me this error: 
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [ConnectApi.ChatterMessage].sendMessage(String, String, String)




ConnectApi.ChatterMessage cm = new ConnectApi.ChatterMessage();               cm.sendMessage(Network.getNetworkId(),'Tagged','005O0000002fLlO');

Comment: The syntax is a bit off. Try this: ConnectApi.ChatterMessage cm = ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.sendMessage(Network.getNetworkId(),'Tagged','005O0000002fLlO');

Comment: @alouie I've updated my question above. the code is already working but it can only send message to other users. 

If I use this code, 
ConnectApi.ChatterMessages.sendMessage('Your post has been flagged as inappropriate',UserInfo.getUserId());

It returns an error ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Too few or too many recipients

Comment: The ConnectApi methods can only run as the current, logged-in user and it's not possible to send a private message to yourself. I didn't see a way to insert new private messages with sObjects. A potential workaround is to have your code insert a custom object to indicate that a private message needs to be sent, and then to run a scheduled Apex job as a different user that queries for instances of the custom object and then sends the message. It's hacky and asynchronous, but the only thing I can think of.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, I can run the schedulable batch apex job using the code below but can I specify the user running that scheduled batch apex if I'm scheduling and executing it through my class? 

Datetime executeTime = (System.now()).addSeconds(1);
String cronExpression = util_Utilities.GetCRONExpression(executeTime);

ScheduledClass scheduledJob = new ScheduledClass();

System.schedule('ScheduledJob ' + executeTime.getTime(), cronExpression,scheduledJob);'

Comment: I don't think so. You'd have to execute System.schedule() as another user separately, at regular intervals.